# Angular $scope.$on в манере отказа от $scope

Tags: angularjs

Я изучаю модный способ писать контроллеры избегая обращения к $scope напрямую.
Есть такой контроллер

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'vAccordion' ])

    .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {

      $scope.panesA = [{
          id: 'pane-1a',
          header: 'Pane 1',
          content: 'Curabitur et...',
          isExpanded: true
        }, {
          id: 'pane-2a',
          header: 'Pane 2',
          content: 'Lorem...'
        }, {
          id: 'pane-3a',
          header: 'Pane 3',
          content: 'Aliquam erat...'
        }];

      $scope.expandCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('expand:', index, id);
      };

      $scope.collapseCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('collapse:', index, id);
      };

      $scope.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {
        console.log('accordionA is ready!');
      });
    });
})(angular);
```

Переписываю так:

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'vAccordion' ])

    .controller('MainController', MainController);
    function MainController() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.panesA = [{
          id: 'pane-1a',
          header: 'Pane 1',
          content: 'Curabitur et...',
          isExpanded: true
        }, {
          id: 'pane-2a',
          header: 'Pane 2',
          content: 'Lorem...'
        }, {
          id: 'pane-3a',
          header: 'Pane 3',
          content: 'Aliquam erat...'
        }];

      vm.expandCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('expand:', index, id);
      };

      vm.collapseCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('collapse:', index, id);
      };

      vm.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {
        console.log('accordionA is ready!');
      });
    });
})(angular);
```

Если у вас большой опыт, тогда смейтесь на здоровье). Для меня будет ценными как ссылка на материал по вопросу, так и переписанный контроллер. Кто не понял в чем проблема, вот

> vm.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {

Если хотите поиграться, тогда вот http://codepen.io/LukaszWatroba/pen/MwdaLo
Я немного обрезал контроллер и вьюху у себя. У меня так как в вопросе, а пример полностью на CodePen.

Я так понимаю ангулярный метод $on есть только в ангулярных обьектах, потому и не вызывается. Тогда как сделать что-то на подобии

```
var $jQueryObjectNow = $('#abcd').jQueryMethod();
```

или заменить конструкцию?

`$scope.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {`

Comment: все просто: события есть только в скопе, поэтому в данном случае нужно использовать скоп

Comment: @Grundy тогда $scope это обязательный параметр функции контроллера или  $scope будет передан автоматически?
Всмысле так
**function MainController($scope) {** или **function MainController() {**

Comment: чтобы использовать $scope, естественно ты его должен получить, поэтому `function MainController($scope) {`

Comment: @Grandy спасибо, ангуляр многое делает вместо разработчиков (если сравнивать с backbone), поэтому и задаю такие удивительные вопросы.

Answer (score 3):

Прежде всего нужно понимать *почему* стараются данные хранить не в `$scope`, а непосредственно в объекте контроллера.

Таким образом решается не всегда очевидное поведение с наследованием скопов во view. Когда непонятно, берется ли свойство из текущего скопа, либо оно будет взято из родителя.

Важно также то, что скопы никуда не исчезают, они все так же создаются и доступны. Именно в них помещается ссылка на экземпляр контроллера, который используется во view.

Так как события не относятся к данным - они остаются в объекте $scope, поэтому для их использования, нужно этот объект получить.

Поэтому вид контроллера может быть таким:

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'vAccordion' ])

    .controller('MainController', MainController);
    function MainController($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.panesA = [{
          id: 'pane-1a',
          header: 'Pane 1',
          content: 'Curabitur et...',
          isExpanded: true
        }, {
          id: 'pane-2a',
          header: 'Pane 2',
          content: 'Lorem...'
        }, {
          id: 'pane-3a',
          header: 'Pane 3',
          content: 'Aliquam erat...'
        }];

      vm.expandCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('expand:', index, id);
      };

      vm.collapseCallback = function (index, id) {
        console.log('collapse:', index, id);
      };

      $scope.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {
        console.log('accordionA is ready!');
      });
    });
})(angular);
```